# How to prevent duplicate UIButton taps in UITableViewCell with RxSwift disposeBag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

First of all sorry for the confusing title, but I actually can't come up with something better (if you do, please edit).

I have an application using Coordinator pattern and RxSwift, so all in all I wan to pass all *navigation* related stuff to Coordinator, so it can handle navigation logic.
In one view controller I have `UITableView` with cells which has `UIButton` inside of them. For that case I have a:

```
actionButton.rx.tap.bind(to: viewModel.chapterAction).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

`chapterAction` is a `PublishSubject<Void>` as it only reflects a button tap, but I need to pass more info to Coordinator, so later I transform this `chapterAction` to:

```
var showChapter: Observable<Chapter> = self.chapterAction.mapTo(self.chapter)
```

And I *assume* that up to this point there's nothing wrong with this code, so in View Controller's `.bind(to: tableView.rx.items...` I have:

```
viewModel.showChapter.bind(to: self.viewModel.chapterAction).disposed(by: viewModel.disposeBag)
```

Since I want to bind this to view controller's `viewModel` and later `subscribe` in coordinator.
It all works ok, but for some cells I get **duplicated** taps, why? I've tried putting `distinctUntil`, `shareReply`, but nothing seems to help my problem and it's not a deterministic one. I *suspect* some reusing to be involved, but I have no clue where to start looking for this issue...

Answer (score 4):

You need to re-initialize the `disposeBag` in `prepareForReuse()` method:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}
```

Then, all previous subscriptions are disposed.

Comment: This isn’t the case - I’m doing this re-initialization, but still duplicates. Though, my code sample says I use dispose bag from viewModel I actually tried every dispose bag I had access from this place - cell’s, viewModel’s, view controller’s

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly what was wrong with my code, but I ended up with adding `mapTo` directly in `tableView.rx.items` binding block. Now it looks like this:

```swift
viewModel.chapterCellViewModels
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ChapterCell.nameOfClass, cellType: ChapterCell.self )) { (_, viewModel, cell) in
        cell.configureCell(with: viewModel)

        cell.actionButton.rx.tap
            .mapTo(viewModel.chapter)
            .bind(to: self.viewModel.chapterAction)
            .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

As I've mentioned in OP - I guess it was due to some reuse etc. but I'm not able to answer why this was happening.